# ImportError: cannot import name 'webdriver' from partially initialized module 'selenium'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, importerror

Here is the code snippet:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

#https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/

service = Service(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get("https://google.com")

time.sleep(2)

driver.quit()
```

After running, I get this error message:

[image: error message]

Comment: Is this script itself named `selenium.py`?

Comment: Rename your script file name and it will remove your circular import issue.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have your script file named as `selenium.py` too, if you change that to something else, it'll start working.

This is being caused as python is trying to import `webdriver` from selenium, but as your file is named `selenium` too, python tries to import from the script itself instead of searching in **site-packages**.